# Paragraphs not displaying on front-end

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I've created some paragraph types and added them to the "basic page" content type. I've filled in some data, but nothing shows up on the front-end. Only the content of ckeditor does. Any idea why this is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post pics of your display settings for the node, as well as any twig template modifications you may have made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it can be a few things...

If that twig template is the node, you would not use `{{ page.content }}`, but rather just `{{ content }}`. `{{ content }}` is the entire render array for the node.

If you wanted to split the fields up within the node twig template, you can use the format `{{ content.field_foo }}`.

It is already set to render the paragraph entity - so this should be all that is needed.

Another thing to check, if `{{ page.content }}` is totally blank, ensure that the **Main page content** block is set to output in the Main Content region of your theme.

Comment: Somehow it started working after a few hours. I'll mark your answer as accepted and delete the question afterwards. Thanks for your time!